# Run and kill java program in background in Linux

Tags: java, linux, background

i have a little java program that i want to run in background (i don't want to block the cli).
I want also have the possibility to kill it (without looking manually for the PID).
I want to create to script:
./start.sh -> starts the java program in background
./stop.sh  -> try to kill the java program (running in background).

Any ideas ?

Comment: `stop.sh` could either try to find the process via tools like `ps` or you could save the PID in a file from `start.sh` and just kill that (assuming you don't start it more than once etc. etc.)

Comment: You can easily set it up as a systemd service and control it that way

Comment: kill is the easiest way to go. Another way is to open a socket in your Java app that listens for a kill message, which I think is the safest (in terms of relinquishing resources in a proper and orderly man) way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start.sh:

```
javaProgram &
pid=$!
echo $pid >/var/run/javaProgram.pid
```

stop.sh:

```
kill $(cat /var/run/javaProgram.pid)
```